Is it possible to define a subclass in python that creates a new atomic attribute?
I'll call an "atomic" attribute of a python class to be one from which all other user defined attributes derive. For example, the attribute a in the class below is atomic to A because all user defined attributes (decorated with @property) derive from it.
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a + 1
    
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a - 1

This is useful to me because I want a to be the only mutable attribute, and if I change a all other attributes will update.
Now suppose I would like to define a new class Z that inherits from A, but has a new atomic unit g. That is, Z will only be initialized some new argument g from which the original atomic attribute a will derive in some way. For example, my first attempt would be:
class Z(A):
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
        super().__init__(a=g**2)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.g**2

Here I declared that a = g**2 and would like to establish g as my new atomic attribute for instances of Z. I attempted to do that by over-writing self.a and forcing it to be self.g**2. However, this throws an error when creating an instance of Z:
    self.a = a
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Presumably because the @property attribute a has already been defined for Z and can't be set again. My solution which I'm not completely happy with is the following:
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a + 1

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a - 1

class Z(A):
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
        super().__init__(a=g**2)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.g**2

Here I made my original class A atomic to _a and then just defined a to be _a. Then in Z I over-write the definition of a. This works as expected, i.e. if I instantiate an instance of Z and change g, all donwstream attributes (b and c) update appropriately.
However, I'm not happy with this because in every instance of Z there is this lingering _a attribute which never gets updated if I change g. For example:
>>> MyZ = Z(4) 
>>> MyZ.b
17 # 4**2 +1 
>>> MyZ.g = 5
>>> MyZ.a, MyZ.b
(25,26) # Updated, good
>>> MyZ._a
16 # outdated value... (4**2)

Is there a better way to do this? Or should I not be trying to do this?

You can create a setter for your property.

What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Beware the XY problem.

"Atomic" has a well established meaning in programming ("executed without interruption"), so I would choose a different term to describe what you want.

@sytech thank you -- I could add a @property for g and use  @g.setter to update a. That will work.
